# Checkbox Stays Checked on Page Refresh

Tags: html, checkbox

This a pretty simple question (I assume).  Probably a repost, but I couldn't find the answer here... so here we go.

I have a checkbox on a page that I want to default to "unchecked" (unless I specify otherwise in my php).

When I refresh the page, if the box was checked, it will stay checked which is no-bueno because checking the box adds a dom element to my page via a function attached to the box. So the problem is if I refresh, the box is still checked, but the dom element doesn't exist (because I haven't fired the function and I don't want to unless the user checks the check box) but the box is *ALREADY* checked and I end up in opposite land where *UN* checking the box creates my dom element and checking it removes it.

Basically, the question is...

Is there a way to default a checkbox to unchecked without javascript?

BTW I haven't checked (no pun intended) in any browsers other than FF 3.5.10

Comment: Working backwards here...how do you get the checkbox to stay checked after a refresh? My form clears, and I actually want it to keep the data. I have an issue where a mistyped captcha clears my form, and I'm not sure how to solve it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See http://weblogs.mozillazine.org/gerv/archives/2006/10/firefox_reload_behaviour.html
(first comment):

> It’s done that way on purpose so if you tap the refresh button you
>   don’t lose your work. There’s an entry in Bugzilla somewhere that’s
>   been WONTFIXed asking for a regular refresh to always reset the form
>   entirely. Basically it’s a backwards-compatibility thing — every
>   browser since NS1.0 (maybe even Mosiac) has done that.
>
> Dynamically-generated pages don’t even reset themselves, though if the
>   expiration is set to 0 and you hit the back button it will give you a
>   fresh form. Also, if the form itself changes (add or remove elements,
>   change the action, etc.) the for will reset on a reload. I haven’t
>   tested it, but setting the form name to something random (assuming you
>   don’t need the name for JS access) might just work. Like ”> in PHP.
>
> As you said, forcing a refresh clears the form, and resetting it does
>   too. Would something like  do
>   what you want (again, not tested)?

Comment: well then, there you go.  Damn you FF!  (just kidding, I love FF, I wish everybody used FF)

Comment: Yea, what's annoying to web developers is, unfortunately, a desired behavior for web users. There have been many times when I've accidentally reloaded a page while writing a long post and was grateful that Firefox kept my form data.

Answer (score 10):

this works for ie
autocomplete="off"

Answer (score 3):

Sure:

```
document.getElementById('my_checkbox').checked = false;
```

Oops, I missed the part about no JS. As far as I know, Firefox retains page state on refresh, so I guess there's no other way.

Comment: yeah, I just hate adding more javascript to my page, as I'll be adding some to CHECK certain boxes.  I guess I can take care of all that at once, but I'd just like to start with a clean slate.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, you just have to add the `<form>` tag with attribute `autocomplete="off"`:

```html
<form autocomplete="off">
     <label for="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
     </label>
</form>
```

Comment: You misspelled autocomplete in the inline codeblock

Answer (score 1):

You can use the parameter autocomplete="off" directly on the input tag